# Steam not opening on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: games, steam, 21.04

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 21.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
Steam client's requirements are satisfied
WARNING: Using default/fallback debugger launch
/home/caio/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Startup - updater built Jun  8 2021 22:23:36
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  44
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Loading cached metrics from disk (/home/caio/.steam/debian-installation/package/steam_client_metrics.bin)
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Checking for update on startup
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Checking for available updates...
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1623193086)
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1623193086, installed version 1623193086, existing pending version 0
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Nothing to do
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Verifying installation...
[2021-06-30 10:11:47] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2021-06-30 10:11:48] Verification complete
Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6501165
Gtk-Message: 10:11:48.685: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 10:11:48.685: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:37496): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:11:48.700: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/main.rc:775: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'

(steam:37496): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:11:48.703: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Yaru/gtk-2.0/hacks.rc:28: error: invalid string constant "normal_entry", expected valid string constant
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  45
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20210630101147_1.dmp[37527]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20210630101147_1.dmp
/home/caio/.steam/debian-installation/steam.sh: line 772: 37496 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER $DEBUGGER_ARGS "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
caio@Caio:~$ assert_20210630101147_1.dmp[37527]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20210630101147_1.dmp[37527]: response: CrashID=bp-8a5af2c4-bb27-4283-a761-04ec12210630
assert_20210630101147_1.dmp[37527]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20210630101147_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-8a5af2c4-bb27-4283-a761-04ec12210630''
```

Comment: What steps did you perform to install it?  Did it work before and just stop?  Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling steam?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar looking errors and done the following to fix it:

1. using "additional drivers" app (got it from ubuntu software), to install nvidia driver metapackage 460
2. run `sudo apt upgrade` as recommended [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/wiki/starting_guide/)